# $Y = AX + \varepsilon$, what is $E(X \ | \ Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a $p$-dimensional real-valued random variable and let $\varepsilon$ be a mean-zero finite variance random variable of dimension $d$ independent of $X$. Let $A$ be a known $d \times p$ matrix.

Let now 
$$
Y = AX + \varepsilon.
$$

Clearly $E(Y \ | \ X) = AX$ but is there a closed form expression of $E(X \ | \ Y)$? Maybe if we assume that $\varepsilon$ and $X$ are Gaussian, we can find a closed form? Any ideas?

Comment: Does $X$ lie in the row space of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking expectations conditional on $Y$,
$$Y = AE\left(X\middle| Y\right) + E\left(\varepsilon\middle| Y\right)$$
so $E\left(X\middle| Y\right)$ is given by the solutions to the linear system $Y - E\left(\varepsilon\middle| Y\right) = AE\left(X\middle| Y\right)$. If $A$ is square and full-rank (hence invertible) then we have the unique closed-form expression $E\left(X\middle| Y\right) = A^{-1}\left(Y - E\left(\varepsilon\middle| Y\right)\right)$. Otherwise, a 'solution' in the least squares sense can be considered as $E\left(X\middle| Y\right) \approx A^{\dagger}\left(Y - E\left(\varepsilon\middle| Y\right)\right)$ where $A^{\dagger}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$. Additionally if we assume $E\left(\varepsilon\middle|Y\right) = E\left(\varepsilon\right) = 0$ (which implies $\varepsilon$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, but does not necessarily imply $\varepsilon$ and $Y$ are independent), then this reduces to $E\left(X\middle| Y\right) \approx A^{\dagger}Y$.